# How to get the first index and last index using multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have one multidimensional array using this array i have to take the first and last index means explode the values and remaining index we have to give static 10 Hrs

```
 $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT date_add(date(d_started_on), interval i day) as allocation_date,t_project,t_assign_to,t_start_time,t_end_time FROM ( SELECT date(STR_TO_DATE(t_started_on, '%Y-%m-%d')) as d_started_on, datediff( date(STR_TO_DATE(t_due_on, '%Y-%m-%d')), date(STR_TO_DATE(t_started_on, '%Y-%m-%d')) ) as days,t_project,t_assign_to,t_start_time,t_end_time FROM task ) as base INNER JOIN nums ON i <= days ORDER BY 1";
$mysql = mysql_query($sql);
$productsArray = array();
while($rowRes = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql)){
    $rowRes['allocated_day'] = $rowRes['allocation_date'];
    $productsArray[] = $rowRes;
}
 $project_name = array();
foreach($productsArray as $key0 => $info) {
    $key1 = $info['t_assign_to'];
    $key2 = $info['t_project'];
    $key3 = $info['allocated_day'];
    $project_name[$key1][$key2][$key3] = $info['t_start_time'].'-'.$info['t_end_time']; 
}
```

> OUTPUT print_r($project_name);

```
    Array
(
    [G2E0357] => Array
        (
            [10001] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-01] => 01:30 PM-02:30 PM
                )

            [10002] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-25] => 10:30 AM-01:30 PM
                    [2018-01-26] => 10:30 AM-01:30 PM
                    [2018-01-27] => 10:30 AM-01:30 PM
                )

        )

    [XPL0315] => Array
        (
            [10002] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-18] => 11:30 AM-07:30 PM
                    [2018-01-19] => 11:30 AM-07:30 PM
                    [2018-01-20] => 11:30 AM-07:30 PM
                )

        )

)
```

Now i want to take the **t_project** array ,

1. allocated_day (Index)
2. $info['t_start_time'].'-'.$info['t_end_time'] (Values)

In this array first index means, i have to explode `-` and i have display exploded **0th index value** then allocated_day array last index means i have to display exploded **1st index value**

> Expected Output

```
 Array
(
    [G2E0357] => Array
        (
            [10001] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-01] => 01:30 PM
                    [2018-01-02] => 10 Hrs
                    [2018-01-03] => 11:30 AM
                )

            [10002] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-25] => 10:30
                    [2018-01-26] => 10 Hrs
                    [2018-01-27] => 01:30 PM
                )

        )

    [XPL0315] => Array
        (
            [10002] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-18] => 11:30 AM
                    [2018-01-19] => 10 Hrs
                    [2018-01-20] => 07:30 PM
                )

        )

)
```

> Updated Expected Answer

```
    Array
(
    [G2E0357] => Array
        (
            [10001] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-01] => 2 Hrs
                )

            [10002] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-25] => 9 Hrs
                    [2018-01-26] => 10 Hrs
                    [2018-01-27] => 4 Hrs
                )

        )

    [XPL0315] => Array
        (
            [10002] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-18] => 8 Hrs
                    [2018-01-26] => 10 Hrs
                    [2018-01-27] => 10 Hrs
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I've updated my anwser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated anwser :

**NB: 01:30 PM-02:30 PM = 1, not 2**

```
$office_start = compute_am_pm_time("9:30 AM") ;
$office_end = compute_am_pm_time("7:30 PM") ;

foreach ($project_name as $assign => $infos) {
    foreach ($infos as $t_proj => $dates) {

        $days = array_keys($dates) ;

        // create a new array :
        $per_assign = [] ;

        if (count($dates) > 1)
        {

            // get first and last dates :
            $first = reset($days);
            $last = end($days);

            // remove first and last dates
            $first_time = array_shift($dates) ;
            $last_time = array_pop($dates) ;

            // get first date
            $begin = substr($first_time, 0,strpos($first_time,'-'));
            $begin_tm = compute_am_pm_time($begin) ;
            $per_assign[$first] = compute_duration($office_end, $begin_tm) . ' Hrs';

            // get static 10hrs (but could be computed)
            foreach ($dates as $day => $time) {
                $per_assign[$day] = '10 Hrs';
            }

            // get last date
            $end = substr($last_time, strpos($last_time,'-')+1);
            $end_tm = compute_am_pm_time($end) ;
            $per_assign[$last] = compute_duration($end_tm, $office_start) . ' Hrs';
        }
        else
        {
            $first_time = array_shift($dates) ;
            list($begin,$end) = explode("-", $first_time) ;

            $begin_tm = compute_am_pm_time($begin) ;
            $end_tm = compute_am_pm_time($end) ;
            $first = reset($days) ;
            $per_assign[$first] = compute_duration($end_tm, $begin_tm) . ' Hrs';

        }

        // assign new values :
        $project_name[$assign][$t_proj] = $per_assign ;
    }
}
print_r($project_name);


/**
 * @param $time_str A time in 12H format ("09:30 AM").
 * @returns the number of minutes since 00:00
 */
function compute_am_pm_time($time_str)
{
    list($time, $part) = explode(' ', $time_str, 2);
    list($hrs, $mins) = explode(':', $time) ;

    $is_pm = strtolower($part) == 'pm' ;
    $hrs = ((int)$hrs) + ($is_pm && $hrs != '12' ? 12 : 0) ;

    return $hrs*60 + $mins ;
}

function compute_duration($end_min, $begin_min) {
    return ($end_min - $begin_min) / 60 ;
}
```

The result :

```
Array
(
    [G2E0357] => Array
        (
            [10001] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-01] => 1 Hrs
                )

            [10002] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-25] => 9 Hrs
                    [2018-01-26] => 10 Hrs
                    [2018-01-27] => 4 Hrs
                )

        )

    [XPL0315] => Array
        (
            [10002] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-18] => 8 Hrs
                    [2018-01-26] => 10 Hrs
                    [2018-01-27] => 10 Hrs
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: ,it is not working properly like suppose start date `2018-01-02 12:30 PM` and due date `2018-01-02 02:30 PM` means time difference should come `2` but based on ur code  it is returning `-10`

Comment: Are you getting my question Mr @Syscall

Comment: @MithunM I've updated the `compute_am_pm_time()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Using your created array, you could use `array_pop` and `array_unshift` to get first and last elements. Then you could iterate over remaining elements.

```
$office_start = compute_am_pm_time("9:30 AM") ;
$office_end = compute_am_pm_time("7:30 PM") ;

foreach ($project_name as $assign => $infos) {
    foreach ($infos as $t_proj => $dates) {

        $days = array_keys($dates) ;

        // get first and last dates :
        $first = reset($days);
        $last = end($days);

        // remove first and last dates
        $first_time = array_shift($dates) ;
        $last_time = array_pop($dates) ;

        // create a new array :
        $per_assign = [] ;

        // get first date
        $begin = substr($first_time, 0,strpos($first_time,'-'));
        $begin_tm = compute_am_pm_time($begin) ;
        $per_assign[$first] = compute_duration($office_end, $begin_tm) . ' Hrs';

        // get static 10hrs (but could be computed)
        foreach ($dates as $day => $time) {
            $per_assign[$day] = '10 Hrs';
        }

        // get last date
        $end = substr($last_time, strpos($last_time,'-')+1);
        $end_tm = compute_am_pm_time($end) ;
        $per_assign[$last] = compute_duration($end_tm, $office_start) . ' Hrs';

        // assign new values :
        $project_name[$assign][$t_proj] = $per_assign ;
    }
}
print_r($project_name);


/**
 * @param $time_str A time in 12H format ("09:30 AM").
 * @returns the number of minutes since 00:00
 */
function compute_am_pm_time($time_str)
{
    list($time, $part) = explode(' ', $time_str, 2);
    list($hrs, $mins) = explode(':', $time) ;
    $hrs = ((int)$hrs ) + (strtolower($part) == 'pm' ? 12 : 0);
    return $hrs*60 + $mins ;
}

function compute_duration($end_min, $begin_min) {
    return ($end_min - $begin_min) / 60 ;
}
```

This will give to array below :

```
Array
(
    [G2E0357] => Array
        (
            [10001] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-01] => 6 Hrs
                    [2018-01-02] => 10 Hrs
                    [2018-01-03] => 2 Hrs
                )

            [10002] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-25] => 9 Hrs
                    [2018-01-26] => 10 Hrs
                    [2018-01-27] => 4 Hrs
                )

        )

    [XPL0315] => Array
        (
            [10002] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-18] => 8 Hrs
                    [2018-01-26] => 10 Hrs
                    [2018-01-27] => 10 Hrs
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Syscall

Comment: I have one more question,My office timing is `9.30` AM into `7.30 PM`,from above query what i want to do means , i have to take first index values suppose 1.30 PM means , we have to do one calculation `1.30 PM ` into `7.30 PM` total `7 Hrs`

Comment: Then i have take last index value suppose `11.30 AM`,we have to do calculation like `9.30 AM` into `11.30 AM` total `2 Hrs`

Comment: @MithunM So, you want to compute the "hard coded" `'10 Hrs'` ? That's it ?

Comment: @Mr Syscall,First and last index value only i have to do the calculation, remaining all `10 Hrs` only

Comment: @MithunM Ok, I understand. I will update my anwser soon.

Comment: @MithunM Could you update your expected output please ?

Comment: Ya sure Mr.@Mr Syscall

Comment: Mr Syscall please below down my `Updated Expected Answer`

Comment: Hai Mr@Syscall,your above query is not working properly in all condition,please see my `OUTPUT print_r($project_name)` and `Updated Expected Answer` when ever coming like condition it is not working

Comment: Mr @Syscall, you are not getting my question means kindly let me know, so that i will explain clearly

Comment: @MithunM I've added a new anwser. Note the **NB**.  Please, do not change your question another time and ask a new question next time. Thanks.Please, let your upvote on my previous anwser for many time I spent on your question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Since data you need to change are in same format and length, I would simply do something like this:

```
foreach ($project_name as $key => $value) {
    $value[0] = substr($value[0], 0, 8);
    $value[1] = "10 Hrs";
    $value[2] = substr($value[2], 9);
}
```